# Prove that $x^{2020} + x^{1011} + 2 x^{1010} + x^2 + x + 1$ does not have a real root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Prove that $$x^{2020} + x^{1011} + 2 x^{1010} + x^2 + x + 1$$ does not have a real root.

---

The degree of the polynomial is $2020$. That's a enough big number. Usually I know some ways for small degree polynomials but it didn't work here. I've been trying to try the sum of squares method but haven't been able to. I tried putting the $x^{1010}$ out of the parenthesis $$x^{1010}(x^{1010} + x + 2) + x^2 + x + 1$$

That didn't work either. I'm looking for a derivative-free solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $x^2+x+1>0$ for all $x,$ it suffices to prove that $x^{1010}+x+2$ is also $>0.$

If $x\le-1,$ $x^{1010}+x+2\ge|x|+x+2>0.$

If $x>-1,$ $x^{1010}+x+2\ge x+2>0.$

Answer (score 9):

Both $x^{1010}(x^{1010} + x + 2)$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ are non-negative functions of $x$, so that any real root of $x^{1010}(x^{1010} + x + 2) + x^2 + x + 1$ must also be a real root of $x^2 + x + 1$. But $x^2 + x + 1$ does not have real roots.

Comment: You didn't prove that $x^{1010} + x + 2\ge0.$

Comment: That's true, I sketched the function and took it for granted. Well, your answer takes care of that inequality!

Answer (score 3):

If $|x| > 1$ then $x^{1010} + x + 2 \ge x^2 + x + 2 > 0$.
If $|x| \le 1$ then $x^{1010} + x + 2 \ge x+2 \ge 0$.
Thus  $$x^{1010}(x^{1010} + x + 2) + x^2 + x + 1 > 0.$$