# Prove that $x^{2020} + x^{1011} - 2 x^{1010} + x^2 - x + 1$ does not have a real root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $x^{2020} + x^{1011} -  2 x^{1010} + x^2 - x + 1$ does not have a real root.

---

[I have been provided a solution for similar polynomial $$x^{2020} + x^{1011} +  2 x^{1010} + x^2 + x + 1:$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4755368)

$$x^{1010}(x^{1010} + x + 2) + x^2 + x + 1$$

Since $x^2+x+1>0$ for all $x,$ it suffices to prove that $x^{1010}+x+2$ is also $>0.$

If $x\le-1,$ $x^{1010}+x+2\ge|x|+x+2>0.$

If $x>-1,$ $x^{1010}+x+2\ge x+2>0.$

I tried the same way but I failed.

$$x^{1010}(x^{1010} + x - 2) + x^2 - x + 1$$

Since $x^2-x+1$ is nonnegative. So it suffices to prove that $x^{1010} + x - 2>0$. But this is wrong by Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I need calculus free solution.

Comment: Do you have a source for this problem?

Comment: Yes @L.F.  of course I have a book for 2020 contest problems but not in English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

want  $$  x^{4n}  + x^{1+2n}  - 2 x^{2n}  + x^2 - x + 1  $$

Well,
$$  \left(x^{2n} + \frac{x}{2}  -1\right)^2 = x^{4n}  + x^{1+2n}  - 2 x^{2n}  + \frac{x^2}{4} - x + 1  $$

so that
$$  x^{4n}  + x^{1+2n}  - 2 x^{2n}  + x^2 - x + 1 =   \left(x^{2n} + \frac{x}{2}  -1\right)^2 + \frac{3x^2}{4} $$

Answer (score 3):

We would like to show that
$$
f(x) = x^{2020} + x^{1011} - 2x^{1010} + x^2 - x + 1 > 0
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

### Case $x \ge 0$

Note that
\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= (x^{2020} - x^{1010} + \tfrac{1}{4}) + (x^2 - x + \tfrac{1}{4}) + (x^{1011} - x^{1010}) + \tfrac{1}{2} \\
&= (x^{1010} - \tfrac{1}{2})^2 + (x - \tfrac{1}{2})^2 + x^{1010} (x - 1) + \tfrac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
so it suffices to show that
$x^{1010} (1 - x) < \tfrac{1}{2}$.

- If $0 \le x < \tfrac{1}{2}$, then $x^{1010} (1 - x) < 2^{-1010}$.
- If $\tfrac{1}{2} \le x < 1$, then $x^{1010} (1 - x) < \tfrac{1}{2}$.
- If $x \ge 1$, then $x^{1010} (1 - x) \le 0$.

### Case $x < 0$

For clarify, we are trying to show that
$$
f(-y) = y^{2020} - y^{1011} - 2y^{1010} + y^2 + y + 1 > 0
$$
for all $y > 0$.

- If $0 < y \le 1$, then
  $$
  f(-y) = y^{2020} + (y^2 + y) (1 - y^{1009}) + (1 - y^{1010}) > 0.
  $$
- If $y > 1$, then
  \begin{align*}
  2 f(-y)
  &= (y^{2020} - 2y^{1011} + y^2)
   + (y^{2020} - 4y^{1010} + 4)
   + (y^2 + 2y + 1) - 3 \\
  &= (y^{1010} - y)^2 + (y^{1010} - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 3 \\
  &> 0 + 0 + 4 - 3 = 1.
  \end{align*}

Comment: how did you prove $x^{1010} (1 - x) < \tfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: @user1210867 By casing over $[0, 1/2)$, $[1/2, 1)$, and $[1, \infty)$.  See edit.